# Problems with JAXB, Marshal, - unable to marshal type "java.lang.String"

Tags: java, string, jaxb, marshalling

i have a problem, I generated the classes using a schema xsd with xjc. when I run the marshal operation I get the following error:

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)  at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)    at prova.StampGenericXML.staticStampGenericXML(StampGenericXML.java:42)     at prova.TestLauncher.main(TestLauncher.java:199) Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(Unknown Source)   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.LeafBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(Unknown Source)  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)  at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(Unknown Source)    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(Unknown Source)     at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Unknown Source)
```

**the portion of the xsd code is:**

```
<xsd:complexType name="formattedText">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Formatted text according to parts of XHTML 1.1  </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" processContents="lax"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

the class FormattedText is:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

/**
 * Formatted text according to parts of XHTML 1.1
 * 
 *

Java class for formattedText complex type.
 * 
 *

The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 *

```
 * <complexType name="formattedText">
 *   <complexContent>
 *     <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       <sequence>
 *         <any processContents='lax' namespace='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'/>
 *       </sequence>
 *     </restriction>
 *   </complexContent>
 * </complexType>
 *
```

* 
 * 
 *

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "formattedText", propOrder = {
"any"
})
public class FormattedText {

@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected Object any;

/**
 * Gets the value of the any property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Element }
 *     {@link Object }
 *     
 */
public Object getAny() {
    return any;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the any property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link Element }
 *     {@link Object }
 *     
 */
public void setAny(Object value) {
    this.any = value;
}

}
```

**this is the class for the marshal operation**

```
public class StampGenericXML {  
static public void staticStampGenericXML(Object objectJAXB, String context) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException{
    try {

        JAXBContext jaxbLocalContext = JAXBContext.newInstance ("org.plcopen.xml.tc6_0201");

        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbLocalContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(objectJAXB, System.out);
    } catch (JAXBException e1) {            
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

When i create a FormattedText object:

```
FormattedText text = new FormattedText();
text.setAny("table");
```

and run the project i have thi error.
Why?
please help me. 
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
text.setAny(new JAXBElement<String>(
  new QName("table"), String.class, "tableContent");
```

Comment: perfect friendly. my fault for not seeing the documentation of JAXBElement. thank you very much