# Wrap a String of an instance of JAXBElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following code,

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestResults.class);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream( "nosferatu.xml" );
TestResults tr = new TestResults();
tr.setUuid(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("uuid"),String.class, "uuidcontent"));
//ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
m.marshal(new JAXBElement<TestResults>(new QName("uri","local"),TestResults.class,new TestResults()), System.out);
```

in which I am trying to wrap the **Java String Class** as a `jaxb element`, since if I do not I get
 the

`unable to marshal type “java.lang.String”` error.

However when I try wrap the `java.lang.string` in a `jaxb element`, I get the following error

`The method setUuid(String) in the type TestResults is not applicable for the arguments (JAXBElement<String>)`

The `setUuid` method looks as follows

```
public void setUuid(java.lang.String value) {
    this.uuid = value;
}
```

How can I then wrap my `String` as a `jaxb element` where this error will not be thrown?

Comment: Your method expects a `String`, but you are trying to pass it a `JAXBElement`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes I know that, however this solution was posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205877/problems-with-jaxb-marshal-unable-to-marshal-type-java-lang-string and the user said it works.

Comment: Notice how their `setAny` accepts an `Object`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis gotcha. is there a way then to make this work for a String value? I will now rephrase my question.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you for jaxb, I don't know it very well. I was just commenting from a syntactical perspective.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis gotcha, thanks. It is still progress toward a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When marshalled as the root object an instance of `String` needs to be wrapped in a `JAXBElement` to provide the root element information (same as for any class without an `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

When marshalled as a field or property value the containing element is normally derived from the containing field/property so a `JAXBElement` by default is not required.

Comment: Yes this class does not have the `@XmlRootElement` annotation when it was generated from `jaxB`. So would I wrap it as an instance of a `JaxBElement` then after I call the `setUuid` method?

Comment: @jgr208 - The generated `ObjectFactory` class should have a create method annotated with `@XmlElementDecl` that will return the `JAXBElement` you need.  See: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: figured it out, wasn't using the generate objectfactory class like you did in your example. Thanks for the help!